# How to pause and resume a spring batch step based on some Kafka event

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch

We are trying to create a central batch service which will invoke batch processes in remote (micro) services. During this, we want to pause step execution untill remote service is not responding back to batch service.
Is this achievable with Spring Batch?

Comment: your question and tags both are irrelevant

Comment: A little more details about your architecture would help in providing correct answer like at what point remote service is called etc etc. That said, Spring Batch Step is a regular Java code and normal Thread wait - notify kind of code would be a raw solution. I don't think pausing a step is natively supported once a step starts executing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try implementing StepListener, where you have beforeStep and afterStep methods, you can control in beforeStep method call to wait until the other service call completes its execution

```
public class StepTwoListener implements StepExecutionListener {
@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Sleep time in ms = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    System.out.println("Before Step Execution");
}}
```

and you can use the listener inside your step

```
@Bean
public Step stepTwo() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepTwo").tasklet(new StepTwo()).listener(new StepTwoListener()).build();
}
```